# JFrame in all spaces on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, spaces

I am trying to make a window in a Java application (a JFrame) follow the user between all Spaces in Mac OS X 10.5 and above, and I cannot seem to find how to do it. I found how to do it Objective-C, but there has to be some way to do this in Java!

How to do it in Objective-C:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/192813-floating-window-across-all-spaces.html

Comment: Isn't window/space configuration handled by osx? For example, I configured osx to put notational velocity on all my windows. Don't know how that works with java apps, or if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's very platform specific, it sounds like you'll have to write some kind of JNI/JNA to do it.  Fortunately, someone might have already done this for you - check out **http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/**

[This thread](http://java.net/projects/rococoa/lists/users/archive/2009-01/message/33) has a little bit of info on the API to get the NSWindow.

Comment: I did look into that, the problem then becomes that I don't actually want to use the native Objective-C class library, since this app also runs on Windows and Linux. But it is a floating utility, and on Mac it gets 'stuck' in a single space. However, I'm willing to write JNI/JNA code if it is possible to do it that way, but I don't want to have to write an entirely separate Mac version due to one issue. EDIT: I just saw your link, I will look into that now and see if it works!